# SSH from Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, quoting

I have a shell script where I am executing ls command from different hosts within it but I am having trouble achieving this. Here is my colde below:

```
#!/bin/sh      
nodes="hostname1 hostname2" 
cmd="ls -ltrha"
for node in ${nodes}; do
    ssh ${node} '`$cmd`'
done
```

The problem with this code is that it can ssh hostname1 perfectly but it doesn't even execute the ls command or even ssh hostname2.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

****New Edit****
I also tried the below one liner, but it only executed the ls without the ssh

```
     ssh hostname1 'ls -ltrha'
```

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Thank you for your comment Cyrus but I don't think the issue is just with quotes. I just tried running a one liner and instead it only excuted the $cmd without executing the ssh commend. Please take a look at my post

Comment: please update your Q to indicate how you are dealing with the `password` prompt from the remote host. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh      
nodes="hostname1 hostname2"
cmd="ls -ltrha"
for node in $nodes; do
    ssh "$node" "$cmd"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do it

```
#!bin/sh
nodes="hostname1 hostname2" 
for node in ${nodes}; do
ssh ${node} 
`ls -ltrha`
done
```